# SetValue within reflected ProperyInfo

Tags: c#, reflection, subclass, propertyinfo

I am using reflection to set a property from within a reflected property. I have to use reflection as I don't know what the type the child propery will be, but each time I get System.Target.TargetException (on the prop.SetValue) prop is pointing to the correct property

I can find lot of examples of the SetValue, the problem that I am having, is I expect related to the fact that selectSubProcess is a PropertyInfo rather than a actual class

```
PropertyInfo selectedSubProcess = process.GetProperty(e.ChangedItem.Parent.Label);
Type subType = selectedSubProcess.PropertyType;
PropertyInfo prop = subType.GetProperty(e.ChangedItem.Label + "Specified");
if (prop != null)
        {
            prop.SetValue(process, true, null);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like process is "Type", not an instance of an object.  in the line

```
prop.SetValue(process, true, null);
```

you need an instance of an object to set, not a Type.

Use "GetValue" to get an instance of the object you care about:

```
public void test()
{
  A originalProcess = new A();
  originalProcess.subProcess.someBoolean = false;

  Type originalProcessType = originalProcess.GetType();
  PropertyInfo selectedSubProcess = originalProcessType.GetProperty("subProcess");
  object subProcess = selectedSubProcess.GetValue(originalProcess, null);
  Type subType = selectedSubProcess.PropertyType;
  PropertyInfo prop = subType.GetProperty("someBoolean");
  if (prop != null)
  {
    prop.SetValue(subProcess, true, null);
  }

  MessageBox.Show(originalProcess.subProcess.someBoolean.ToString());
}


public class A
{
  private B pSubProcess = new B();
  public B subProcess
  {
    get
    {
      return pSubProcess;
    }
    set
    {
      pSubProcess = value;
    }
  }

}

public class B
{
  private bool pSomeBoolean = false;
  public bool someBoolean
  {
    get
    {
      return pSomeBoolean;
    }
    set
    {
      pSomeBoolean = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Having a little bit of trouble converting your code, my GetValue and SetValue require an extra parameter, and when I get them to Null ... I get the same error as before

Comment: What .Net version are you running?

Comment: Code has been updated to .Net 2.0, although the only change is adding the null arguments, which it sounds like you've already done.  Can you get my code to work as is (i.e. don't try to convert it to your structure quite yet)?

Comment: Also, make sure when you SetValue that you pass the instance of the parent of the boolean, not an instance of the boolean itself.  The information on which property to set in the parent is provided by the PropertyInfo